# Arbitrary functions can be expanded by basis functions of invariant subspaces of a group

Tags: group-theory, group-representations

On page 96 of M. S. Dresselhaus's [Applications of Group Theory to the Physics of Solids](http://web.mit.edu/course/6/6.734j/www/group-full02.pdf), it is said that

> Any arbitrary function $F$ can be written as a linear combination of a complete set of basis functions $f^{\Gamma_{n'}}_{j'}$
>   $F= \sum_{n'}\sum_{j'} f^{\Gamma_{n'}}_{j'} |\Gamma_{n'}, j'\rangle$

in which $|\Gamma_{n'}, j'\rangle$ represents the $j'\text{-th}$ basis function of the $n'\text{-th}$ irreducible representation of some finite group.

I don't understand why an arbitrary function can be expanded.

**Here is my understanding:**

Given a finite group $G$, by studying its character table, we know the invariant subspaces of the group. Finding the set of basis functions of each of the invariant subspaces of $G$ gives us the set of basis functions {$|\Gamma_{n'}, j'\rangle$}.

What is so special about this set of functions? Clearly, the size of the group determines the size of the set {$|\Gamma_{n'}, j'\rangle$}, does it mean that a smaller set of {$|\Gamma_{n'}, j'\rangle$} has the same 'expressive power' as a larger set?

---

**EDIT:**

Inspired by ZeroTheHero's answer, here is what I understood:

A real-valued function defined on space $X$ is a map 
$$\text{A point in } X \rightarrow \Bbb R$$
Given a finite group $G$, we construct a linear representation of which in space $X$. Since the representation can be decomposed into the irreducible representations of $G$, space $X$ can be decomposed into the invariant subspaces of $G$. So we say any arbitrary function F can be written as a linear combination of a complete set of basis functions.

Given a space $X$, there are many sets of basis functions that we can find. The invariant subspaces of a group (as long as a linear representation of the group can be constructed in $X$) just provides a way to partition the space and simultaneously leads us to those basis functions.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Comment: I voted to migrate this to Math.SE.

Answer (score 1):

In a large number of situations, the actual functions of interest not transform by a single *irreducible* representation, and it's useful to write them in terms of irreducible pieces since these transform only amongst functions within the same irreducible irrep.

The simplest example would be the function $f=x_1+y_2$, which is clearly not invariant under permutation since $P_{12}f= x_2+y_1$.  However, the functions
$$
f_+= x_1+y_2+ x_2+y_1\, ,\qquad f_-= x_1+y_2 -(x_2+y_1)
$$
transform irreducibly under permutation (here up to a sign) of the indices, and indeed
$$
x_1+y_2 = \frac{1}{2}(f_++f_-)
$$
Another obvious example would be the two-particle spin state
$$
\vert +\rangle_1\vert -\rangle_2 =
\frac{1}{2}
\left(\vert +\rangle_1\vert -\rangle_2+
\vert +\rangle_1\vert -\rangle_2\right)+
\frac{1}{2}
\left(\vert +\rangle_1\vert -\rangle_2- 
\vert +\rangle_1\vert -\rangle_2\right)
$$
where  $\frac{1}{2}
\left(\vert +\rangle_1\vert -\rangle_2 \pm 
\vert +\rangle_1\vert -\rangle_2\right)$ are symmetric/antisymmetric w/r to permutations.

This holds quite generally.  Maybe the better known example would be how an generic function $f(\theta,\varphi)$ can be expanded as a sum of spherical harmonics $Y_{\ell,m}(\theta,\varphi)$, keeping in mind the spherical harmonics are basis functions for $SO(3)$ irreps.

Comment: This is very helpful! I have added my understanding into the body of my post, could you check whether I understand it correctly?